# Kept asking for site password despite Master Password set

Tags: winscp

I have been using WinSCP for many years without issues. I had to switch to a new PC and installed the latest WinSCP 6.1.1. I have created a Master Password. However, when opening a site, it doesn't prompt me for the Master Password. Instead I have to enter the site password each time.

Must a site be explicitly added to be covered by the Master Password? I don't remember having to do this in the past.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you didn't save your password to your stored site (or you didn't save the site at all). So there's nothing to be protected by the master password.

- Enter your credentials, including the password, on the Login dialog.
  https://winscp.net/eng/docs/ui_login
- Click *Save* and make sure the *"Save password (protected my master password)"* checkbox is ticked (it should be by default).
  See https://winscp.net/eng/docs/ui_login_save

Comment: Oh, I have to click the Edit button first, instead of straight to the Login button. It was years ago since I last did this.